# how is the OLD and NEW prefix used in postgresql stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

how is the OLD and NEW prefix used in a postgresql stored procedure?

I saw a snippet like this in a stored procedure

```
IF (MY_VARIABLE = 'UPDATE' AND (OLD.user_code != NEW.user_code OR NEW.log_time != false)) THEN
       SELECT name,lastname INTO target_name,target_lastname FROM users.user 
       WHERE user_code = OLD.user_code;
ENDIF
```

does the `OLD` means previous value of `user_code` column?

does the `NEW` means a newly created record, a new `user_code` value ?

OR does the `NEW` means the "updated value" of the `user_code` ?

Comment: See the docs [OLD/NEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) for explanation.

Comment: I am pretty sure you did not see that in a procedure but in a (trigger) _function_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  it's a part of a stored procedure but being triggered by a trigger function

Comment: 1) There is a difference between a [Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) and a [Procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html), not the least of which is a procedure cannot be used by a trigger. 2) A [Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) is statement that executes a function.